# Global StackInbox widget links to wrong pages

Tags: bug, status-completed

The global StackExchange inbox notification thingamajig in the top left corner links to the wrong pages on apple.stackexchange.com. It tells me I have a reply for my question X, but upon clicking the link I'm taken to a completely different question Y. Only seen this problem on the Apple stack so far.

Answer (score 1):

this bug should be fixed now.